# Computer and power supply

Tags: laptop, power-supply

If the computer is given power supply with the battery removed from it, and suddenly the supply goes off, in such an event what happens to the computer? what happens to it in the long run?

Comment: You mean a laptop? Considering most PCs don't have batterys

Comment: This question shows little research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RAM is discharged causing all unsaved work and states to be lost.

In Windows, the registry sees this as a dirty shutdown and does a check disk on reboot. It is possible files that are critical are in the middle of a write (Reg keys included) and cause boot / performance issues in the long or short term. Although thats more of an OS question than a PC problem.